# Can we convert ANSI encoded CSV file to utf-8 encoded file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have been looking answer for this question for days. Actually, I need to upload the ansi encoded csv file to web service. The front end application reads the file encode it's content to base64 and send it to web service in json format. But when I try to read file with javascript, non-english unicodes just gets changed to something else.

Is there any way to read ansi encoded csv file in javascript and converting its encoding to utf-8?

With my research, I think is impossible. The file must be in UTF-8 itself.

Any suggestions would be great help.

Comment: You mean ISO 8859-1 or Windows CP1252?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry I misread you question at first. Your trouble comes at the moment of reading the file. It is useless to try to convert the file after contents were ruined when trying to load in a wrong encoding. I came up with FileReader API in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/gq53t0dm/) inspired by [this example](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=iLqARKYneo0) and [article on html5rocks](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api#readastext)

```
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.readAsText(f, 'windows-1252');
```

The only trouble I see here is there is no auto encoding detection. You need to know encoding before loading the file.

Comment: Just the above code works if the file(csv) type is UTF-8 otherwise some characters do not read by javascript.

Comment: To try utf8 package I am not in node server environment. I have already tried running the above code with no success. I found the root of non english unicodes corruption is while reading file from file system. When an html file button is trigger. I am  getting file content from the triggered event. By the time when it print it out in console. The non english unicodes already gets corrupted. And when I execute above codes with those data, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @ManiRai, the utf8 package is usable in browser, it is mentioned there. You can just download the [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js/master/utf8.js) and include it in you html page

Comment: Awesome kirill... Its working like a charm now..... Thank you very much... But I think I need to improve my question too.....

Comment: I have csv files generated by APEX which are in ANSI encoding which maps to windows-1250 -> reader.readAsText(file, "windows-1250");